# How to initialize "RInside" instance in a function NOT main function, and call it multiple times without getting "R is already initialized"?

Tags: c++, rcpp, rinside

I would like to use RInside in a function that is NOT the main function in my c++ program. After debugging, I found out that the function works for the first round and I get the output as expected but when it is called for the second time my program stops and I get the error message "R is already initialized". Can anybody help me to have a workaround to overcome this issue?
please see below a simple example to clarify that.
**I need to call mainR() function from a function(my_func) that is also NOT the main function.I am actually dealing with a bit complex program so my_func will be also called multiple times, which made initializing RInside useless..**
Sorry, the code doesn't look realistic but I just wanted to simplify and clarify my question.

```
#include <RInside.h> 

void mainR()
{

    RInside R; // create an embedded R instance

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n"; // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)"); // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

}

void my_func()
{

mainR();
mainR();
.
.
}
```

Comment: (I didn't downvote.) I am sure we have that covered somewhere in an example. In essence it is _your application_ that has to ensure the RInside object is allocated once, after which tasks are handed to the one preserved instance.  We do have numerous examples in nine different subdirectories -- I am pretty sure this has been covered.

Comment: **Throwing static before RInside did the trick, it worked. Thanks a lot @JaMiT**

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel for your response, I was searching in the examples of RInside but couldn't find a similar case according to my understanding. Apparently, it is not about an issue in RInside but about my weakness in C++.

Comment: @ahmdbi92 I've converted my comment to an answer. If you discover any negative side-effects, the answer might need to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear (I am not an expert on RInside) that an application must have no more than one `RInside` object created over the course of an application's lifetime. This corresponds to C++'s concept of "[static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration)". When a variable is defined in the `main` function, the difference between "automatic" (the default) and "static" duration is usually insignificant, but it is highly significant for a function called more than once.

Adding the keyword `static` indicates that a variable is to have static storage duration.

```cpp
static RInside R; // create an embedded R instance
```

This has two effects on a variable defined inside a function. First, the object is not destroyed when the function ends. Second, the object is not re-initialized when the function is called again. (It is still initialized when the function is called the first time.) This avoids the error where R was initialized twice. However, it also comes with a caveat—the object retains state between function calls. One must assume that the `RInside` object might have been used earlier, even at the beginning of `mainR()`.